# Hello, can I want to know how to install and use swiperjs

Tags: swiper.js

I am new to swiper js and I wanna know how to use it. Am confused, what's the difference when I install swiper js and when I import it

Comment: Please make sure to read how to ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . and try to search with [google](https://www.google.com/) before you ask a question .

Answer (score 0):

When you install it via `npm`, you would use something like Webpack, Bable or Browserify to build it into your website. While this is useful for large scale projects, it's not something I would recommend getting into if you are relativly new to web development.

The easier way to use it is via a CDN (content delivery network). This is just a website that hosts all the code for you, which you can import yourself. For Swiper.js, you could add this to your HTML code:

```html
<!-- Add to your <head> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<!-- Add to the bottom of the <body> -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Then, you can just use Swiper.js in your code like normal :)